# Synchronizing a Block of Code - Exercise 13-2

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

In this exercise, we will attempt to synchronize a block of code. Within that block of code, we will get the lock on an object so that other threads cannot modify it while the block of code is executing. We will be creating three threads that will all attempt to manipulate the same object. Each thread will output a single letter 100 times and then increment that letter by one. The object we will be using is StringBuffer. We could synchronize on a String object, but strings cannot be modified once they are created, so we would not be able to increment the letter without generating a new String object. The final output should have 100 A’s, 100 B’s, and 100 C’s, all in unbroken lines.

1. Create a class and extend the Thread class.
2. Override the run() method of Thread. This is where the synchronized block of code will go.
3. For our three thread objects to share the same object, we will need to create a constructor that accepts a StringBuffer object in the argument.
4. The synchronized block of code will obtain a lock on the StringBuffer object from step 3.
5. Within the block, output the StringBuffer 100 times and then increment the letter in the StringBuffer. You can check Chapter 5 for StringBuffer (StringBuilder) methods that will help with this.
6. Finally, in the main() method, create a single StringBuffer object using the letter A, then create three instances of our class and start all three of them.

Solution:

public class OCJPThread extends Thread{

```
StringBuffer sb;
public OCJPThread(StringBuffer sb) {
    this.sb =sb;
}


public void run(){
    synchronized (sb) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
            System.out.print(sb);

        System.out.println();
        sb.setCharAt(0, (char)(sb.charAt(0)+1));


    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("A");
    OCJPThread t1 =new OCJPThread(sb);
    OCJPThread t2 =new OCJPThread(sb);
    OCJPThread t3 =new OCJPThread(sb);

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
}
```

}
output 
Thread-0
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Thread-2
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
Thread-1
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC

Question : If I am using Stringbuilder or StringBuffer, it doesn't matter as I am using syncronized block.

But if I use synchronized(this) instead of stringbuffer object. Output is unpredicatable. As string buffer is already syncronized, why do we need to do it ourselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StringBuffer` is synchronized, but only on each individual method call. This means that when you are not using synchronization, the part that prints the value of the string buffer is not done within a synchronized block. One of the other threads can update the buffer during that time. When this happens, the print will show the new value. You can't really know which thread will update the buffer first.

Also, a thread may change the value between the call to `sb.charAt()` and the call to `sb.setCharAt()`. So the result of the increment itself may be unpredictable.

Note: synchronizing on `this` means each thread is synchronizing on a different lock, so it's like not synchronizing at all.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the same reference to all three threads. If they synchronize on this, then they can all write to the `StringBuffer` at the same time. If they synchronize on the common `StringBuffer`, then only one thread can access it at a time.